# CSS: How can I make a 1:1 div that is 100% of its parents width or height, whichever is smaller?

Tags: css

This pen probably explains my problem best:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwQpLy?editors=110

I'm using the following trick to keep the box constrained to a 1:1 ratio:

```
.squarebox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.squarebox::before {
  padding-bottom: 100%; 
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.content {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
}
```

But, I'd like the box to always fill the parent's width or height, whichever is smaller. In the above example, the box only ever fills the parent's width.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYQpqp?editors=110

The parent needs to be position:relative, the .content div needs to be width:100%; height:100%; as well as position:relative with top, right, bottom and left set to 0.

I stripped out the squarebox div.

```
.squarebox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  background:orange;
}
```

Comment: "fill the parent's width or height, whichever is smaller".  I see now.  You should look into Flex Grid, you might find something that solves the issue there, or else you could go to javascript to brute force it.